# creating a frame in an old tv closet to hang a tv too big for the closet

Tags: walls, television, closet, frame, mount

We have a tv closet. We bought a new tv and the tv doesn't fit in the closet anymore. I would like to hang the tv up against the closet. I  would make a wooden frame with studs in the closet. Do you think it will be strong enough to hold the tv and the wall mount?  That way we don't need to destruct the closets and we can still use them. Anybody know what size of studs I best use. I took a picture and drew the frame on it that I would like to make. Also a picture of the tv. (75inch) Any suggestions or ideas are always welcome.
[image: frame drawing]

[image: tv]

I would like to add some more pictures to show how the closet is made. It was built to measure so not from a shop. The mount I bought is one that is adjustable so I can still pull the tv more out and use the cabinets. the tv weighs 37kg with the standard that I will remove when on the wall.

[image: closet 1]
[image: closet 2]
[image: closet 3]

Comment: How is the frame attached to the opening? In theory, yes, if this is secured to studs on either side and the TV is if vaguely reasonable weight this should be more than good enough.

Comment: What are these cabinets made of? If they're 3/4" melamine coated particle board (as is common from IKEA or other "flat pack" shelving, or built by "custom closet" companies, you _might_ get away with it. If it's made out of actual, solid wood (as often made by a local custom cabinet builder, _not_ a national chain of installers), then there's a pretty good chance this will work.

Comment: Also, it may depend on how solid the connection is between the horizontal white board at the bottom of the opening and the brown cabinet below it, and how sturdy that brown cabinet is. It appears that your framework (you'd want to use 2x4" studs, as is common in house framing) will primarily rest on the brown cabinet, so it has to take the weight of the TV, plus the framing, plus the 3/4" sheet of plywood that you'll cover the framing with.

Comment: If you want to be able to use the cabinet space, rather than "replicate a studwall" over it, put in framing just where your TV mount needs attaching, and subframing to tie that to the cabinet structure, leaving most of the space open. You'll need an arm-type mount  so you can move the TV out of the way if you expect to open the cabinet door on the left side. *(or, y'know, fight the marketing pressure equating size of TV to your worth as a person and return it for a TV that fits the space)*

Comment: Get a projection screen and a projector TV. Hang it at the top of the closet. Now it goes away.
Or put the TV on the ceiling (should be thin enough to allow the top closet doors to open and have it go down when you want to watch it.